# ASP.NET MVC: Optionally render element attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know there is some syntax with ? to optionally render attribute.
But I can't find it now that I need it ...

Something like:

```
 < input checked=<%? model.IsActivated % >  ...
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Since it seems that nobody knows... perhaps it was some different view engine.
Thanks for answers any way :)

Comment: Be more specific with what you want. Not very clear. What does the optional attribute depend on, that is: when should it be rendered and when not?

Comment: It depends on boolean value after ?. If boolean evaluates to true, the attribute is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input checked="<%= model.IsActivated ? "checked" : string.empty % >"...
```

But the presense of the "checked" attribute might cause it to be checked, I can't remember. But if that's the case then you'll want

```
<input <%= model.IsActivated ? "checked=\"checked\"" : string.Empty %> ...
```

EDIT: btw its called the [ternary(? or conditional) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(VS.80).aspx)